# Why do we assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra in this 2003 paper of Bobkov and Tetali?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, sobolev-spaces, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory

In [Bobkov and Tetali - Modified Log-Sobolev Inequalities, Mixing and Hypercontractivity](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ebobko001/papers/2003_STOC_BT.pdf) (extended version [Modified Logarithmic Sobolev Inequalities in Discrete Settings](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10959-006-0016-3.pdf)), at the beginning of section 3, the authors give two axioms about $\mathcal{A}$. Axiom 1 is about $\mathcal{A}$ being an algebra. I do not see where this axiom is being used. Any ideas?

Conference version: *Bobkov, Sergey; Tetali, Prasad*, [**Modified log-Sobolev inequalities, mixing and hypercontractivity**](https://doi.org/10.1145/780542.780586), Proceedings of the thirty-fifth annual ACM symposium on theory of computing (STOC 2003), San Diego, CA, USA,. New York, NY: ACM Press (ISBN 1-58113-674-9). 287-296, electronic only (2003). [ZBL1192.60020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1192.60020).

Journal version: *Bobkov, Sergey G.; Tetali, Prasad*, [**Modified logarithmic Sobolev inequalities in discrete settings**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10959-006-0016-3), J. Theor. Probab. 19, No. 2, 289-336 (2006). [ZBL1113.60072](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1113.60072).

Comment: Where in the cited document does A appear?  What page, paragraph?

Comment: @KenW.Smith: p290, Axiom 1. So I haven’t managed to digest the paper yet, but is it important that $f^2\in \mathcal A$? (I notice that $f^2$ appears in various places; and a linear space of functions is closed under squaring if and only if it’s closed under taking products).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you. Yes, if there is a need for $f^2$ to belong to $\mathcal{A}$, it would explain the need for Axiom 1. But why should $f^2\in\mathcal{A}$ hold? From my understanding, $\mathcal{A}$ only influences the definition of $\mathcal{E}$ (see Definition 3.1).

Comment: @KenW.Smith $\mathcal{A}$ appears in the first paragraph of section 3 ("POINCARE AND LOG-SOBOLEV IN ABSTRACT SETTINGS"). You can easily find it by searching for `Axiom 1` using ctrl+F and reading the text above it.

Comment: As a general tip, when you mention a paper, I suggest giving a full citation instead of just a link.  It helps people find the paper more reliably.  (In particular, your link to the extended version could only be used by people whose institutions participate in OpenAthens.)  Also, I feel it is a courtesy to the authors to mention their names and the other info about their paper.  There is a "cite" button in the question editor that will give you a full citation with DOI and Zentralblatt link.  I've added citations to your post - perhaps you could double check that they are correct.

Comment: I also don't immediately see this assumption used explicitly.  However, I would note that they are using a very simplified definition of "Dirichlet form".  In the more usual development, a Dirichlet form $\mathcal{E}$ is defined on a dense subspace $D(\mathcal{E})$ of $L^2(M,\pi)$, which should be thought of as a space of "finite energy" functions having one "derivative" in $L^2$, like the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}_0$.  Then it is a *theorem* that the bounded functions in $D(\mathcal{E})$, that is $\mathcal{A} := D(\mathcal{E}) \cap L^\infty(M)$, do in fact form an algebra.

Comment: The standard reference for Dirichlet forms is Fukushima-Oshima-Takeda, *Dirichlet Forms and Symmetric Markov Processes*.  I am pretty sure this theorem can be found there.

Comment: As already noted by @AnthonyQuas: Axiom 1 is less about $\mathcal{A}$ being an algebra and more about having $f^2$ well-defined so that the log-Sobolev inequality in the form of (3.2) makes sense. Similarly, Axiom 2 is used to state the log-Sobolev inequality in the form of (3.3).